# Strange behavior for /index.php/foo

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website at http://www.mywebsite.com/~me/ and I want these behaviors:

1. http://www.mywebsite.com/~me/index.php should redirect to http://www.mywebsite.com/~me/
2. A URL pointing to something that doesn't exist should redirect to http://www.mywebsite.com/~me/404.php

In looking around for solutions, I found these snippets to include in my httpd.conf file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~me/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /~me/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com/~me/ [R=301,L]
```

and

```
ErrorDocument 404 /~me/404.php
```

These snippets create behavior 1 just fine, and for the most part behavior 2 as well. However, instead of http://www.mywebsite.com/~me/index.php/foo redirecting to the 404 page, it redirects to http://www.mywebsite.com/~me/index.php.

How would I change these snippets to get the behavior I want?

Comment: Have you restarted the server since writing the redirect?

Comment: @deniatus Yes, I have restarted the server. My guess is that it has something to do with php queries (such as /index.php?foo=bar